# Pylons and Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, pylons

The following is my oauth template

top.location.href='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=${config['facebook.appid']}&redirect_uri=${config['facebook.callbackurl']}&display=page&scope=publish_stream';



Click here to authorize this application

When I hit the page I am prompted to login (desired), upon login I am redirected in a loop between a permissions page and an app page.

My controller looks like:
class RootController(BaseController):

```
def __before__(self):
    tmpl_context.user = None
    if request.params.has_key('session'):
        access_token = simplejson.loads(request.params['session'])['access_token']
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
        tmpl_context.user = graph.get_object("me")

def index(self):
    if not tmpl_context.user:
        return render('/oauth_redirect.mako')
    return render('/index.mako')
```

I'm guessing my settings are off somewhere, probably with the callback.

Not to sure if it is an issue with my code or the python sdk for facebook.

Comment: Hmm, which flow are you trying to use? If you are using the "authorization_code" flow (or "Server-side" flow documented in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), you are missing, or are leaving out in your example, the part where the user is redirected back with an authorization code, which your application needs to exchange for an access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should modify your code to look like this

```
def index(self):
    if request.params.has_key('session'):
      access_token = simplejson.loads(request.params['session'])['access_token']
      graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
      tmpl_context.user = graph.get_object("me")
      return render('/index.mako')
    return render('/oauth_redirect.mako')
```

and on your href url change redirect_uri to next and point it to your index view on your app

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=${config['facebook.appid']}&**next**=/app/index&display=page&scope=publish_stream